# reverse K node in given linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

The passed list is 1->2->3->4->5 and node is 2 then output should be 2 1 4 3 5 but this code is showing 1 4 3 5 
and for 1 2 3 4 5 6 and 3
it is showing 3 6 5 4

Node type

```
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
    Node(){
        next = NULL;
    }
};


Node* reverseKNode(Node* head_ref, int k){

    Node* current = head_ref;  
    Node* next;
    Node* prev = NULL;  
    int count = 0;  

    /*reverse first k nodes of the linked list */
    while (current != NULL && count < k)  
    {  
        next = current->next;  
        current->next = prev;  
        prev = current;  
        current = next;  
        count++;  
    }  

    /* next is now a pointer to (k+1)th node  
    Recursively call for the list starting from current.  
    And make rest of the list as next of first node */
    if (next != NULL)  
        head_ref->next = reverseKNode(next, k);  

    /* prev is new head of the input list */
    return prev;  
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this with your debugger? BTW I don't see the logic between 1->2->3->4->5 and 2 1 4 3 5. Please [edit] and elaborate.

Comment: I doubt the error is reverseKNode(...). Please paste the complete code here. One quick guess would be to set init value of `next` to `NULL`: `Node* next = NULL;`

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The error in your part of code is :

- `Node* next;` , in this the initial value should be set to `NULL`.

  Node* next = `NULL` ;
- There is no point of using

  `Node(){
      next = NULL;
  }`

in your code, you may remove it.

Making the above changes in `reverseKNode()` the function to reverse k nodes in the the linked list would be correctly executed.

And after this, if the function to push  the node is properly implemented, then you will get the desired output.

Hope this helps!!